# FFMPEG Fade in and Fade out for Overlay

Tags: android, cmd, ffmpeg

I'm trying to add Overlay-Pictures to my video via FFMPEG (on Android). For know I managed to display the Image between a certain time span. But now, additionally, I want to add a fade in and fade out animation.
Here is what I have so far:

```
ArrayList<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>(); cmd.add("-i"); 
cmd.add("video.mp4");
cmd.add("-i");
cmd.add("../image.png");
cmd.add("-filter_complex");
cmd.add("overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2:enable='between(n,1,12)'"); 
cmd.add("out.mp4");
```

How do I need to add the Fade in and Fade Out options.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You fade the image in `rgba`. Example:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=color=black -loop 1 -i logo.png -filter_complex "\
[1:0] format=rgba,fade=in:st=0:d=3:alpha=1,fade=out:st=6:d=3:alpha=1 [ovr];\
[0:0][ovr] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2\
" -t 10 -y out.gif
```

`format=rgba` - use RGB format with alpha channel for transparency

`fade=in:st=0:d=3:alpha=1,fade=out:st=6:d=3:alpha=1` - fade in starting at 0s for 3s with alpha, fade out starting at 6s for 3s with alpha.

`overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2` - overlay centered on source

[image]

Comment: Can you add some explanation as to what the individual options are ? 
That would make for a good answer